# Is there any way to find out which application if any uses the camera?

Tags: camera

I got a camera failed warning (which disappeared after rebooting): is there any way to find out which application if any uses the camera?

[image]

I use Samsung Galaxy S3 with Android 4.1.2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All Android Apps on the Google Play Store have a list of Permissions they use which includes the use of the camera.

It is tedious to look through the permissions of each app manually from the Play Store.

Instead try using an app that lists the app permissions and list apps using the Camera/Microphone permissions.

Eg. [Permissions Observatory](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.quet.android.po) (I have no connections with this app, I found it randomly, and I don't use it)